# RPM .spec file and versioning

Tags: rpm, versioning, specfile

I have a .spec file in the `/root/rpmbuild/SPECS` directory and I have a Version file in the `/root/rpmbuild/SOURCES` directory. The Version file contain a version number similar as 1.4.5, how can I take it into the .spec file `Version:` tag?

We are manage the version numbers with a shell script in every build what Gitlab CI trigged by pushesand save it to a file.

If it is possible I want to run a shell script similar as `cat Version` and take it to the Version. Current code: `Version: %(cat Version)`, i didn't find other solution, but it is take nothing to the Version.

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done? What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling ready

Comment: Similar answered question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771728/define-version-with-script-in-rpm-spec-file